# Inconsistent results from multiple subject area in OBIEE

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I need to create a dashboard compiling results from different subject areas. I used a simple tutorial I found to create these results. However, it looks like something is not correct. I tried to look up but I couldn't find any valid suggestion.

Here below snapshots of what has been done and the issue.

First criteria:
[image]
Second criteria:
[image]
Result columns:
[image]

Below is a snapshot from the output excel file. My issue is the column **TOOL_FAMILY** is showed as "0". Although the fields **GIN**  and names worked.

Actual results exported in Excel
[image]

Could someone help me locate where I messed things ? Please note that I tried getting data on the second part by itself and it worked, so I'm sure the field **TOOL_FAMILY** is not empty.

Please let me know if anything else is needed to clarify things and get this done.

UPDATE:

I managed to find the SQL command sent to the server :

```
SELECT saw_0, saw_1, saw_2, saw_3, saw_4, saw_5, saw_6, saw_7, saw_8, saw_9 
FROM ((SELECT "DIM_LOCATION"."LOCATION_CODE" saw_0, "DIM_EMPLOYEE"."GIN" saw_1, "DIM_EMPLOYEE"."FIRST_NAME" saw_2, "DIM_EMPLOYEE"."LAST_NAME" saw_3, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."JOB_RUN_NUMBER" saw_4, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."MWD_RUN" saw_5, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."LWD_RUN" saw_6, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."DD_RUN" saw_7, '0' saw_8, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."RUN_PROFILE" saw_9 FROM "Job Crew Functions" WHERE ("DIM_DATE"."PERIOD" >= '2015-01') AND ("DIM_EMPLOYEE"."GIN" = 4532214)) 

UNION 

(SELECT "DIM_LOCATION"."LOCATION_CODE" saw_0, 0 saw_1, '0' saw_2, '0' saw_3, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."JOB_RUN_NUMBER" saw_4, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."MWD_RUN" saw_5, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."LWD_RUN" saw_6, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."DD_RUN" saw_7, "DIM_TOOL"."TOOL_FAMILY" saw_8, "DIM_JOB_RUN"."RUN_PROFILE" saw_9 FROM "Eqp Job Run" WHERE saw_1 = 4532214)) t1 

ORDER BY saw_0, saw_1, saw_2, saw_3, saw_4, saw_5, saw_6, saw_7, saw_8, saw_9
```

Is there a way to check the issue based on the above code sequence ?

Comment: Thats the logical SQL. Can you grab the physical SQL that actually gets passed down to the DB? Also, if you changed the hard coded 0 in the first report to a hard coded 1, would your results say 1?

Comment: Thnx for the answer. Regarding the code, that's the only code I can get. and for the hard coded value,when I change it to "1" in the first report, it will still give me the correct values

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with your first union analysis. Can you try giving SUM(0) instead of 0 ?

Comment: Hello, What you suggested didn't change the output, it's still showing 0 for results.